# upload file not working in google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

it should works but hitting the submit button redirect my page to http://localhost:8082/sign (http://localhost:8082 being the path to my app). There's no such path in my application thus it return a link broken page. Is this a common problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but this isn't an App Engine problem. If you do a form post to a URL that doesn't exist, it will return a 404 (I'm suspecting you modified the `guestbook` app, which posts to `/sign` and didn't change where the post on that app goes to).